# Lecture notes by Rudolf Mössbauer

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model, soft-question, specific-reference

Rudolf Mössbauer was an excellent lecturer. He gave lectures on Neutrino Physics, Neutrino Oscillations, The Unification of the Electromagnetic and Weak Interactions and The Interaction of Photons and Neutrons With Matter. Many students were motivated to change to TU München, because Mössbauer taught there.

Where one can find the lecture notes for the courses he taught (web references, libraries, ...)?

Comment: found this https://www.mediatheque.lindau-nobel.org/videos/35914/2001-masses-of-the-neutrinos/laureate-moessbauer